# FireFox gets ns_error_net_interrupt when clicking on loaded page

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, cache, connection, firefox

FireFox is connecting to my website, but accessing already visited pages would randomly  not connect resulting in a

> **Secure Connection Failed**

Chrome and Microsoft Edge are not having that problem.

What is strange is that reloading the page is also not working. I need to *force* reload the page by way of using Shift and reload - and then I get the page back, and will always load when using shift and reload.

How can I prevent this from happening?

The html pages are pre-compresses Brotli files served by an Apache 2.4.57 server.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault                  "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType text/asp          "now"
    ExpiresByType text/html         "now"
    ExpiresByType text/css          "access plus 1 day"
    ExpiresByType video/x-m4v       "access plus 15 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg         "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg        "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif         "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png         "access plus 5 days"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf   "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon      "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(html)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "access plus 3 hours"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I am using these default Connection Settings in FireFox:

[image: Use system proxy settings]

SSL info when the connection is not made and I get a `ns_error_net_interrupt` error:

[image: Validation: Not specified]

SSL info after reloading that same page (using Shift and reload) -- it works again:

[image: Validation: Let's Encrypt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed like FireFox did not like to reconnect onto pages that expired.

```
    ExpiresByType text/asp          "now"
    ExpiresByType text/html         "now"
```

When changing it to

```
    ExpiresByType text/asp          "access plus 3 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/html         "access plus 3 hours"
```

things started working.